# Why does not the true match 'true' with double equals sign '==' in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, if-statement, casting

This small portion of code took a long time to be noticed.

I thought if I do the following, it would be fine

```
if('true' == true) {
    alert("Does not happen");
}
```

But it does not pass the if condition.

I thought the double equals `==` matches the  value not the type as matching the type is the job of `===`.

Now my questions are why wasn'the `true` typecast to `'true'` or why is it checking for the type of these operands?

Comment: 'true' is string, `true` is boolean i.e string == boolean

Answer (score 8, accepted):

```
'true' == true
```

This is what happens here (according to the [rules](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3)):

-- convert boolean to a number (rule 7):

```
'true' == 1
```

-- convert 'true' to Number (rule 5):

```
Number('true') == 1
```

-- `Number('true')` is `NaN`:

```
NaN == 1
```

-- return false (rule 1.c.i)

`==` is indeed confusing, but it makes some sense once you understand the rules:

- garbage is equal to garbage (undefined == null)
- no booleans (they're compared as numbers)
- if one of the parts is a number, compare numeric
- if one of the parts is a string, compare as strings
- otherwise, a and b must be the same thing.

Comment: Best (and simplest) explanation so far!

Answer (score 4):

The `==` of Javascript is one of the worst part of the language that is build under no comprehensible logic... We suffer an old spec, that's just the answer.

Take a loot at the complete Facepalm:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Sameness

**edit for the edit**

Yeah, the 'typecast' is not working as we could expect... there is no other answer.. :/

Comment: IMHO, this does not answer the question.  The conversion of both operands is _exactly_ following the specification and thg435's answer should be accepted.

Answer (score 4):

See the [rules for `==`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3).

`Type(x)` is a string and `Type(y)` is a boolean. So Step 7 applies. It converts the boolean to a number and compares it to the string. The string you have won't match any number.

Comment: I don't think this is how this algorithm works here. The correct sequence of steps is 7-5-1.c.i.

Comment: @thg435 — Argh! I missed the `Type(y)` what with all the `Type(x)`s in there.

Answer (score 1):

in JavaScript boolean, The result is 1 if the argument is true. The result is +0 if the argument is false.  So, `'true' == true` is equivalent to `'true' == 1` which is of course, false.