# WTFJS: true != 'true'

Tags: javascript, type-conversion

### Short version of the question

`true == 'true' //evaluates to false`

Why?

### Full version

OK, I know that using `==` instead of `===` is a bad practice, but this question was in the **FrontendLeague** quiz today and I was very surprised with the answer.

My logic was quite straightforward (all the following statements evaluate to `true`):

```
Boolean("true") === true
String(true) === 'true'
'true' ? true : false === true
```

Nevertheless:

```
'true' == true // false
true == 'true' // also false
```

As it was stated by Kyle Simpsons in [this great video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2pL28CcEijU), most of wtfjs'es aren't actually so wtf and are fully alright according to js specs.

So, could you please explain why `'true' == true` is false?

Thanks!

#### P.S.

I'm sorry if this question was already asked, but it's pretty hard to find smth by keywords `javascript` and `true` (`wtfjs` gives nothing).

Best regards, Alexander

## UPD

Sorry for duplicate, the complete answer can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/21042112/2044039), as mentioned in the comments by Joachim Rohde.

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21041619/why-does-not-the-true-match-true-with-double-equals-sign-in-javascript

Comment: `'true'` is a string, and not the same thing as a boolean value, `true`. `Boolean("true") === true` because the "truthiness" of `"true"` is `true`. Same for `'true' ? true : false === true`. JS evidently converts `true` to the string `'true'` when you apply `String(true)`. But ultimately, `true` and `'true'` are NOT the same thing. The first is a boolean value, the second is a string.

Comment: @lurker I understand that, but ``==`` was used, not ``===``.

Comment: @AlexanderM. Have you read the answer at the linked question?

Comment: @Barmar yes, thanks, that's what I was looking for but haven't found :)

Comment: If `'true' == true` is false, then JS isn't converting `'true'` as a string to a boolean value based upon its truthiness. You'll need to dig into the JS documentation regarding implicit type conversion to determine what it does here before the actual comparison.

Comment: Reading the ES5 documentation you can read this on section 11.9.3: 

If `Type(x) is String`, then return `true` if `x` and `y` are exactly the same sequence of characters (same length and same characters in corresponding positions). Otherwise, `return false`.

Comment: Javascript uses `Abstract Equality Comparison Algorithm` and according to it if one of the operands is boolean then it is first converted to number (i.e. true -> 1 and false -> 0) and then compared.

Read the 6th point

http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.9.3

Comment: @ZohaibIjaz would you care to post your comment as an answer? (because it's actually the bast answer on this question).

Comment: I would like to post it as an answer but this question has been marked as `duplicate`. If you want to encourage me, vote up for above comment.. and Thanks for your appreciation...